# Actionscript - Video Player Help! - Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, video-streaming, netstream

I've been trying for days to figure out how to get a video to play in flash and I have got pretty much nowhere. I have the code below but have no idea what else to try to get it to work. Can anyone please help?

```
var conn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
conn.connect(null);

var nstream:NetStream = new NetStream(conn);
nstream.setBufferTime(10);

trailer.attach(nstream);
nstream.play("arthur.flv");
```

Comment: Have managed to get it to work. I have no idea what I did but it's working so i'm happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot one crutial part, you need to add the NetStream to a video object after the NetConnection has connected successfully.

```
var connection = new NetConnection();
connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
      switch (event.info.code) {
          case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
              connectStream();
              break;
          case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
               trace("Stream not found: " + videoURL);
                break;
          }
}

function connectStream():void {
    stream = new NetStream(connection);
    stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
    stream.client = new CustomClient();
    var video:Video = new Video();
    video.attachNetStream(stream);
    stream.play(videoURL);
    addChild(video);
}
```

Take a look at the AS3 NetStream docs [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html). Theres ALOT of info and examples there to get you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

Is trailer added to the stage? Like this:

```
var trailer = new Video(); 
trailer.attachNetStream(nstream); 
addChild(trailer);
```

Also have you checked that the NetStream doesn't produce an error? Like this:

```
nstream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler); 
nstream.play("video.flv"); 
function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void{ 
    trace(event);
}
```

Edit: Also have you check the net status and security errors? Like this:

```
nstream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
conn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
conn.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);

function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
     switch (event.info.code) {
         case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
             connectStream();
             break;
         case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
             trace("Unable to locate video: " + videoURL);
             break;
     }
} 

function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
    trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what's the problem? Is your video object visible but just black and nothing happens?